# ubuntu installer fails to recognize an empty partition

Tags: dual-boot

I have successfully installed ubuntu alongside with Win 10 on two of my computers.  What I did was to follow the Gary Newell article " How to install ubuntu linux alongside Windows 10 (UEFI), that is to shrink the Windows partition using Windows Diskmanager, and then use USB containing ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso to boot the temporary version of ubuntu, and then click on the install icon.  However, with the third computer (a new Dell desktop), there was something wrong because the "Installation type" panel did not have the usual several choices, and had only two.  In any case, the installer began installing ubuntu in some small partition, and the process became aborted.  (When I shut off the temporary version of ubuntu, I keep getting thousands of lines of error messages, and I have to force shut-off by holding on the ON button of the computer.)
There are two probably linked problems now.  1. I cannot remove this remnant of faulty installation.  2. When I try to install ubuntu, it does not recognize an unallocated 100 GB partition on hard disk, and says that there are no bytes on my computer.  Thus although I can run fdisk -l, and see that the open partition is not recognized, I cannot run anything else because of this supposed lack of space.  Your help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Unallocated space on the disk is not a partition, so not listed with `fdisk -l` or `parted -l`. Has Windows been installed on the disk? If yes, can you still boot to Windows? Which installation type did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to change this unallocated partition into a simple (active) partition using Windows DiskManager, and even to a formatted (EXT3) partition by using EaseUS Partition manager.  The ubuntu installer still sees only the non-existent tight space, which the pop-up in the desktop says is absolutely full (/usr, /var, etc.) at 4.7 GB, and fails to see the 100GB partition in the hard disk.